# XCode 5 is "Unable to process this app at this time due to a general error"

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, store

I've created my app, tested it, and now all that's left is submitting it to the App Store. But when I go to "Validate" it, I get this error: Unable to process app at this time due to a general error. What does this mean? What is the "general error"? I have Googled this, and heard that at certain times, it's just been a problem with Apple's servers - that users retried it after a an hour, sometimes a day, and it worked. But this has gone on for about a week now. What is the problem, and why won't my application validate?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues look to have been resolved by Apple.  If you look at your Provisioning Profiles, you should notice that Apple has removed your app's Distribution Profiles.  To get your submission working again, all you have to do is recreate your App Store and Ad Hoc provisioning profile, but make sure to use a new name and you should be good to go.  You were not alone on this one.  A bunch of people experienced the same problem.

Comment: Thanks! Why can't I use my old names? And what happened to the provisioning profile of an app already on the app store, and how does its deletion affect that app?

Comment: You don't have to change your App's name.  Only the Provisioning Profile. When I went into my Apple Provisioning Profiles section and saw the Ad Hoc and App Store profiles were removed, I tried to recreate them with the same profile name as before, but I got an error saying that the name already existed.  All I did was add a "2" to the profile name and all was good.

Comment: Oh yeah, I know how to change the name - just wondering if it would affect my apps in any other way. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it would affect your apps in any bad way.